# Navigation of Pop and Push not working in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have two screens. First screen has following code

```
NavigationLink(destination: SecondScreen()) {
                    Text("Scan Qr Code")
                }
```

The `NavigationLink` navigates to second screen which works as expected. In the second screen

```
struct SecondScreen: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation

    var body: some View{
       Button("Done") {
                    self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
   }}
```

The button in second screen pops to first screen which works as expected, but as soon as I come back to first screen and I click  `NavigationLink`, it does not move to second screen.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425183/cant-do-a-simple-navigate-to-view-and-back-swiftui-navigation-bar-button ? Isn’t this the same well known bug?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Use a button on the first screen instead of the navigation link and use that button to pop out a sheet. I tested this and it worked for me!

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var showingAddExpense = false

var body: some View {

    NavigationView{

        Button(action: {

            self.showingAddExpense = true

        }) {

            Text("Button")

        }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddExpense) {
            SecondScreen()
            }
    }
}
}    


struct SecondScreen: View {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation

var body: some View{

    NavigationView{

        Button("Done") {
             self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
         }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It presents the second screen as a modal which can dismissed by user on swiping on top which I don't want